What is the Flight Path Angle Derivative?
I have an assignment which involves a rocket flight path. The angle the rocket makes to the Earth is called the flight path angle and when the rocket is in a freefall parabolic curve, there is a time derivative of the flight path angle, but I cannot find an equation for this!
If flight path angle is denoted as $\gamma$, the initial velocity of the rocket is $v_0$ and the angle at which it launches is $\theta_0$, gravity is $g$ and time is $t$, the flight path angle is given by:
$$\gamma = \arctan\left(\frac{v_0 \sin(\theta_0) - g t}{v_0 \cos(\theta_0)}\right)$$
Other than deriving this which turns into a very complex derivative, is there an equation for $\large\frac{d\gamma}{dt}$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I fixed it as much as I could and was told not to repost, so is this question able to be opened for answers?

Your flight angle equation doesn't make sense. Please check it. The argument of arctan needs to be a pure number, but in your equation it has units of velocity (distance/time). I suspect that it's supposed to be something like $\gamma = \arctan\left( \frac{v_0 \sin(\theta_0) - g t}{v_0 \cos(\theta_0)} \right)$

@AndyDufresne one thing I'm still not sure I understand is why you're trying to compute $\dot{\gamma}$ but on the other hand saying you want to do it without differentiating... why not? But anyway, first ensure the expression for $\gamma$ is correct, as PM 2Ring remarked.

So you're just asking for someone to take the derivative for you and give the final result?

Nevermind, thank you all anyways. I fixed the problem.
